# textjoin multiple lookup results?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to auto-populate Table 2 with content from Table 1 A2:18.

I've manually filled in three of the cells in Table 2

- 1-1: Textjoin contents of Table 1 A2:18 for all instances that (Table 1
  D2:D18=1) AND (Table 1 E2:E18=1)
- 2-2: Textjoin contents of Table 1 A2:18 for all instances that (Table 1
  D2:D18=2) AND (Table 1 E2:E18=2)
- 1-3: Textjoin contents of Table 1 A2:18 for all instances that (Table 1
  D2:D18=1) AND (Table 1 E2:E18=3)

Two questions:

1. What's the formula that achieves the desired result for a given cell, which could then be modified for each of the cells in Table 2?
2. Is there a way to make said formula and array formula for the entire Table 2?

[mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZq6U.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine FILTER and TEXJOIN functions to obtain the correct result. Try the formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE, FILTER($A$2:$A$18,($D$2:$D$18=$H5)*($E$2:$E$18=I$4),""))
```

- `FILTER($A$2:$A$18,($D$2:$D$18=$H5)*($E$2:$E$18=I$4),"")`: filters Table 1 based on values from Possibility and Consequence column/rows from Table 2. An empty string is displayed when there is no value.
- `TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE, FILTER($A$2:$A$18,($D$2:$D$18=$H5)*($E$2:$E$18=I$4),""))`: joins the results from the Filter function.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly. 

Comment: @lllusion See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers).